# java Swing how consume document event

Tags: java, swing, events, key-events, documentlistener

I want consume a DocumentEvent captured into insertUpdate method of a DocumentListener
I don't see any way to prevent as a KeyEvent (e.consume()).

I don't want use the key listener because can't prevent the clipboard events (Copy Paste).
How I work with this events?
How I can raise Document events since cose?

```
    Isbn13TextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            e.consume();   //Not Exists, How consume a copy paste?
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}   
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what it is you are trying to achieve...

### You could...

Use a `DocumentFilter` which will allow you to filter input before it reaches the underlying `Document`.  This is used by the `Document` itself and therefore is not depended on how the content is being added/removed from the `Document` but the `Document` itself.

Take a look at [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) and [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) in particular and [here](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for examples

### You could...

Make the field non-editable...

```
Isbn13TextField.setEditable(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How consume a copy paste?

You can't. A DocumentEvent is generated AFTER the Document has already been updated.

If you just want to disable the copy/paste functionality of a text field then you can remove the Key Bindings:

```
KeyStroke copy = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control C");
textField.getInputMap().put(copy, "none");
```